# What VBScript can I use to populate a field with text using the ArcGIS field calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, vbscript, string, null

I need to populate one field in the attribute table of a File Geodatabase with text. Every entry in the field is set to a Null value and text entry isn't conditional upon any other factor. Every entry in the field needs to have the exact same text. The field is a string field.

I'm sure there's an easy way to do this with VBscript in the field calculator, but I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: Have a look here: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm

Comment: I looked through this page before posting the question. If what I'm looking for is in here, I didn't recognize it as such. From what I saw, this page contains a lot of examples of what can be done to edit or draw from existing string entries, but nothing for how to populate a series of empty fields. Do you see something I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're trying to update all values of a string field to say something, just right-click the field and go to field calculator and type "something" into the input box. Ignore the codeblock if all you need is a simple string, and uncheck that checkbox next to it unless you need it for good measure.

If you want your field to become null then type None, no quotes, with the n capitalized. That will enter null values.

Also be sure you don't have any features selected if you want to update everything. This tool is selection sensitive.

If you're trying to nest the call to calculate field values in another script then that's another matter.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed to know. I had already tried this method, but I only tried it with single quotes or no quotes. I didn't even give double quotes a thought because those are normally reserved for number calculations.